# Is there a way to see when lambda function was deployed and who deployed it?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, monitoring

I think the question title is self-explanatory. My problem is I want to see when and who made last deployment. Wondering if there's a way to find this info anywhere across the **AWS management console**.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to AWS CloudTrail -> Event history, and search for Event name: `UpdateFunctionCode20150331v2` or other API calls which you define it as a "deployment". The result is sorted by event time.